# h2o-wave: ui event without ui update

Tags: h2o-wave

I would like to respond to a button click without updating or changing the ui (e.g. just do a `print()` for now). If I try with h2o-wave v1.0.2 on Win10-22H2, the ui seems to hang in an infinite loading spinner.

This behavior only applies to `mode='unicast'`, which is the default. In case of `mode='multicast'` and `mode='broadcast'`, the ui and the app behave as expected (i.e. `print()` works fine, ui stays responsive).

The problem seems to be independent of browser (tried with Firefox 122.0.1 and MS-Edge 121.0.2277.112).

In the following boilerplate, every works fine, i.e. `print()` and ui updates happen as expected:

```
from h2o_wave import main, app, Q, ui

@app('/buttons', mode='broadcast')
async def serve(q: Q):
    if not q.client.initialized:
        q.page['form'] = ui.form_card(box='1 1 2 2', items=[
            ui.buttons([
                ui.button(name='btn1', label='BTN-1'),
                ui.button(name='btn2', label='BTN-2')
            ]),
            ui.text_m(name='text', content='Click on a button ...'),
        ])
        q.client.initialized = True
    if q.args.btn1:
        print(f'{q.args.btn1=}')
        print(f'{q.args.btn2=}')
        q.page['form'].text.content = 'btn1 was pressed.'
    if q.args.btn2:
        print(f'{q.args.btn1=}')
        print(f'{q.args.btn2=}')
        q.page['form'].text.content = 'btn2 was pressed.'
    await q.page.save()
```

If line `q.page['form'].text.content = 'btn1 was pressed.'` is removed, the ui seems to hang in an infinite loading spinner (tried to post an image, but I am new on stackoverflow hence not yet allowed).

This holds true indipendent of applying `await q.page.save()` or not.

The application works fine as soon as I use `mode='multicast'` or `mode='broadcast'` (which is not what I need in my case).

What would be the correct way in `mode='unicast'` to handle a button click without updating the ui?

Comment: I came across the same problem too and ended up updating a meaningless variable in the meta. Would like to know if there's a proper way to handle it